# Access locals() of imported module via threading in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

My question is how is it possible to check that a local variable is created during function execution in imported module.

For example, I want to detect the moment of creation of variable "c" from the chk_local() function:

```
# module1
def test():
    print "hi"
    print "hi1"
    print "hi2"
    c=250
    print "hi3"
    print "hi4"
    print "hi5"





# main
import threading
import module1 as m1

def chk_local():
    while 1:
        if 'c' in m1.locals():   # does not work
            break
        print "local not detected..."

m1_thread = threading.Thread(target = m1.test)
chk_thread = threading.Thread(target = chk_local)
chk_thread.start()
m1_thread.start()
chk_thread.join()
print "done"
```

Comment: "locals of imported module" doesn't mean anything. In your example, `c` is local to the `test` function - it only exists in the function's frame during the function execution (and there can be more than one active frame for this function if you have multithreading or recursive - even indirectly recursive - calls). The fact that it's in another module is totally irrelevant, and it will never appear in `locals()` call __outside__ the function itself.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, I want to do some code "just before" something in other function happens (i.e. variable c is created). My problem can be solved by other means, but now I am just curious about whether the proposed approach is possible.

Comment: The current approach is not feasible for what you are trying to do, for the reasons @brunodesthuilliers highlighted.

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What you need is some synchronization between the threads. You could use a `threading.Event` for that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `locals()` function does return variables from your current local scope (as the name states). To solve your problem however, `c` is local to your `test` function scope. AFAIK, you cannot dynamically access any nested scope in runtime automagically using the `locals()` function, unless you populate the contents of `locals()` within every local scope's end to the global scope.

**EDIT1**

(What you might do however is to use the python `inspect` lib for the checking because the variables declared within a function scope cease to exist when the function ends.)

**EDIT2**

Another thought that popped to my mind is that threads do not have shared memory unless you give it to them which makes the intended check even harder as you can see [in this blog post](http://slinkp.com/python-thread-locals-20171201.html).

Comment: I was thinking about using inspect. But looks like it gives rather the opposite - access parent namespace from child.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply test If you want to detect the moment of creation of variable "c" from the chk_local() function:

This should be your # module1

```
#module1
def test():
   print "hi"
   print "hi1"
   print "hi2"
   c=250
   print "hi3"
   print "hi4"
   print c
```

This should be your # main file

```
 import threading
 import module1 as m1

 def chk_local():
     m1.test()

 m1_thread = threading.Thread(target = m1.test)
 chk_thread = threading.Thread(target = chk_local)
 chk_thread.start()
 m1_thread.start()
 chk_thread.join()
 print "done"
```

O/P will be:

```
hi
hi1
hi2
hi3
hi4
250
hi
hi1
hi2
hi3
hi4
250
done
```

You can check that the c value is assigned.

Comment: How does this solve the question posed by the OP? OP wants to know: "I want to detect the moment of creation of variable "c" from the chk_local() function". I don't see how `print` does the job of checking if the variable from the other threads local namespace exists.